# strcmp only works at the start of a loop

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, strcmp

I've been trying to create a simple program that loops through an array's members and scan the characters looking for a set specific character. I have ran into an issue where `strcmp()` only works at the start of the loop. I'm struggling to understand why this happens and any help would be appreciated.

```
char *file[3] = {"!x", "!!x", "x!"};

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(file) / sizeof(file[0]); i++) {
  char *line = file[i];
  printf("\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(line); i = i + 1) {
    char character = line[i];
    if (strcmp("!", &character) == 0) {
      printf("[YES] %c\n", character);
    } else {
      printf("[NO] %c\n", character);
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

> ```
> [YES] !
> [NO] x
>
> [YES] !
> [NO] !
> [NO] x
>
> [NO] x
> [NO] !
> ```

Comment: Why do you use a **string** compare function to compare single **characters**?

Comment: you may have undefined behaviour: nothing guarantees that the pointer on a char has a zero somewhere near since it's not a string.

Comment: The comments here about a null-terminate string being required are, of course, correct. The behavior still seems strange since, in this case, we know what comes after `&character` since we know the rest of the characters in the string.  It's not clear to me why it misbehaves in this specific way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strcmp` function expects the address of a null terminated string.  Instead you're passing it the address of a `char`.  `strcmp` then attempts to read memory locations past `character`, resulting in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The real issue however is that you don't want to compare strings.  You want to compare characters.

```
if (character == '!') {
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, you're supplying wrong argument to `strcmp()`, the `&character` is not a pointer to a *string*.

Quoting `C11`, chapter int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);

> `int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);`
>
> The `strcmp` function compares the string pointed to by `s1` to the string pointed to by
> `s2`.

So, it expects both the arguments to be of *string* type, which in your case is not.

You can simply use the comparison operator `==` to compare `char`s, like

```
 if (line[i] == '!')  //notice the '' s, they are not ""s
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp()` compares null terminated strings.  In the code:

```
char character = line[i];
if (strcmp("!", &character) == 0)
```

the `character` is not a null-terminated string.  It is accidental that it works at all.

You need something more like this to compare strings:

```
char character[2] = { line[i], '\0' };
if (strcmp("!", character) == 0)
```

Or like this to compare characters:

```
char character = line[i];
if (character == '!')
```